# How to get more Entety from jsp and send list<Entety> to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I learn JSP. I have always problem when want to work with more Object in JSP. With `<c:forEach ...>` write table  and evry row is one Book. For every book I can change some attribute or with checkbox takeonly books where is checkbox true .

How can I take all books form  form with edit attribute and that list send to servlet ...?

OR how can take checked books in list and send to servlet .

When I work with one attribute or one Object I know , but this is problem for me.

this is form where I write all books

```
<form action="/libraryWeb/editBooks" method="post">
<table>

    <tr><td> Autor </td> <td> Title</td> <td> Years </td> <td> Description </td> </tr>

<c:forEach var="oneBook" items="${books}">

    <tr>
        <td> ${oneBook.autor} </td>
        <td> ${oneBook.title} </td>
        <td> ${oneBook.year} </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="author" value="${oneBook.description}" ></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="idBook" value="${oneBook.id}"/> </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" >Edit book</td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need assign same name to checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="edit"  value="${oneBook.id}">Edit book</td>
```

And catch it on Servlet side

```
String[] toEdit = request.getParameterValues("edit");
```

This way you will get book ids needs to be edit

Comment: ok... but one question , if I checked 2 of 4 checkboxs , how to take only value from that chackbox  .

Comment: If you check 2 of 4 you will get only 2 ids in String[] toEdit array

Comment: thanks a lot ...   Can i ask you one more question, I take value from one fille , but , how to take all the books from the table and send the list<book> to  servlet?